# Do I get email notifications for favorited questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, bookmarks

I would like to track questions which I don't have anything to contribute to.

Comment: If you'd like to make it a feature request, why not head over to [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), where you will have a greater audience?

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I use the favorites as more of a bookmark for future reference, rather than a track changes. I'm on the fence about this request.

Comment: I don't see the harm in it if it were given its own email setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do that. However, you can subscribe to questions using the RSS feed on their page. Example: https://meta.superuser.com/feeds/question/2164

[image]

Comment: A little disappointed by that.  I figured favoriting a question would be a means to show interest in it without necessarily endorsing it, and notifications about it would be a logically response from StackOverflow.  But I now know what to do.  Thanks!