# Is there a way to get a email whenever there's a new answer in a thread?

Tags: feature-request, email

Is there a way to get an email alert whenever there's an new update (such as an answer or a comment) on a thread? I know you can just use IFTTT (check out [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com)) and set up a trigger, but I want to know if you can do that without having to sign up for another service.

Comment: Your own posts or someone elses?

Comment: Anyone, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 9):

You can request [email notifications for your inbox, if you haven't accessed it in a while](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/), which takes care of answers to your own questions, and comments to your posts or addressing you.

While you can mark questions as favorites by clicking the star, and have them show up [in your user profile](https://superuser.com/users/305751/java-thunder-man?tab=favorites), there's [no email notifications](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3613/do-i-get-email-notifications-for-favorited-questions) for it.

[There's also an RSS feed for arbitrary tag subscriptions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6751/rss-feed-for-favorite-tags).

Comment: Adding to this; there's a nice app that provides enhanced RSS feeds: http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source

Answer (score 4):

As of March 2020, you can [follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) somebody else's question and be notified of any new answers; you will also be notified for edits to and comments on the question though. You can combine that with the setting to receive [emails for unread notifications](https://superuser.com/users/email/settings/current), as @DanielBeck suggested.

There is also an [RSS feed for a single question](https://meta.superuser.com/feeds/question/7781) which can be found in the right sidebar, under the Hot Network Questions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working but inefficient solution regarding its time effort, of course the main answer is better:

- Run a scheduled scraper (take an easy DIY scraper or program a scraping script) on the question's link every x hours / days.
- Check the size of the output against the past.
- Write a script to "send a mail if diff", or you might perhaps find a scraper that already offers this feature (please comment if you know one).